# How to animate default splash screen in nativescript angular

Tags: nativescript-angular

I was wondering how to animate the default splash screen which comes with nativescript, possibly the logo? 
Is there a way of adding some css animation to the splash_screen.xml file found in the drawable folder? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nativescript-splashscreen](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-splashscreen/) plugin to add animation in your splash screen. You need to update your AndroidManifest.xml e.g.

```
<activity
  android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
  android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
</activity>
<activity 
  android:name="co.fitcom.SplashScreen" android:noHistory="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Actually i wanted to use this plugin but i failed to understand that part. Like which android:name should i change; the android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity" or "co.fitcom.SplashScreen"